# ant how to compare a property and a string value

Tags: ant

I have a problem with my ant script. basically i want to read a property and compare it with a string.

```
<property name="server_environment" value="local"/>
...
<condition property="blabla2">
    <equals arg1="local" arg2="local" trim="true" forcestring="true"/>
</condition>

<condition property="blabla">
    <equals arg1="{$server_environment}" arg2="local" trim="true" forcestring="true"/>
</condition>
```

Now in the output we get (after turning -debug on)

```
Setting project property: server_environment -> local

...


Condition true; setting blabla2 to true
Setting project property: blabla2 -> true
Condition false; not setting blabla
```

I do not understand why blabla evaluates to false here. Perhaps something is going wrong when reading the server_environment property. But i am not sure what.

Answer (score 0):

Apparantly i needed to change to position of the $. I changed

```
<equals arg1="{$server_environment}" arg2="local" trim="true" forcestring="true"/>
```

Into

```
<equals arg1="${server_environment}" arg2="local" trim="true" forcestring="true"/>
```

Now it does set the property correctly.